# Merging word documents C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to merge c# documents. My idea is to have a master document and just append the other documents to this master document. Environment is in SharePoint, so basically the documents exist in the document library and I have no problem with my code being able to find the documents. Once I locate them programattically I have no clue how to open and merge them. I have been searching and seems to be like OpenXML SDK 2.0 is a way to do it, but I am not familar with that tool at all and was trying to see if their is a way to do it with the current tools I have in Visual Studio 3.5 . Either using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word** or something else. From what I understand, the actual files are stored in the content database as binary form so the physical file doesn't actually exist, so I cant just easily open them with word. Any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link is exactly what you're looking for:

[Merging Word Documents on the Server Side with SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff797985.aspx)

There's a little Open Xml, but nothing too bad. If you decide that this isn't giving you the control you need, you can check this article out:

[Creating Documents by Using the Open XML Format SDK 2.0 (Part 3 of 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469465%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2007 so neither of these solutions will work

Comment: The only (free) alternative I can offer is to do it manually using the OpenXml SDK. There are a number of good articles on how to do that...just search on "Eric White", who is the SME for the OpenXml SDK. If you're willing to put down some money to save some time and learning curve, you could take a look at the Spire.Doc solution below.

Comment: thanks, I was able to use openxml and figure how to make it work for SP 2007

Answer (score 0):

The following script, taken from [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), could help you to get a clue about how to merge .doc files. Be careful with the license if your going to distribute it.

You need to invoke the script from C# using the following:

```
wscript.exe "C:\<path_to_the_script>\merge-doc.js" merged.doc theirs.doc mine.doc base.doc //E:javascript
```

This is the script code, only for doc, there is other for docx that I have not included here, but you can take a look installing Tortoise SVN.

```
//
// TortoiseSVN Merge script for Word Doc files
//
// Copyright (C) 2004-2008 the TortoiseSVN team
// This file is distributed under the same license as TortoiseSVN
//
// Last commit by:
// $Author: tortoisesvn $
// $Date: 2008-12-05 17:38:43 +0100 (Fr, 05 Dez 2008) $
// $Rev: 14781 $
//
// Authors:
// Dan Sheridan, 2008
// Davide Orlandi and Hans-Emil Skogh, 2005
//

var objArgs,num,sTheirDoc,sMyDoc,sBaseDoc,sMergedDoc,objScript,word,baseDoc,WSHShell;

// Microsoft Office versions for Microsoft Windows OS
var vOffice2000 = 9;
var vOffice2002 = 10;
var vOffice2003 = 11;
var vOffice2007 = 12;
// WdCompareTarget
var wdCompareTargetSelected = 0;
var wdCompareTargetCurrent = 1;
var wdCompareTargetNew = 2;

objArgs = WScript.Arguments;
num = objArgs.length;
if (num < 4)
{
   WScript.Echo("Usage: [CScript | WScript] merge-doc.js merged.doc theirs.doc mine.doc base.doc");
   WScript.Quit(1);
}

sMergedDoc=objArgs(0);
sTheirDoc=objArgs(1);
sMyDoc=objArgs(2);
sBaseDoc=objArgs(3);

objScript = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if ( ! objScript.FileExists(sTheirDoc))
{
    WScript.Echo("File " + sTheirDoc +" does not exist.  Cannot compare the documents.", vbExclamation, "File not found");
    WScript.Quit(1);
}
if ( ! objScript.FileExists(sMergedDoc))
{
    WScript.Echo("File " + sMergedDoc +" does not exist.  Cannot compare the documents.", vbExclamation, "File not found");
    WScript.Quit(1);
}

objScript = null

try
{
    word = WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application");
}
catch(e)
{
   WScript.Echo("You must have Microsoft Word installed to perform this operation.");
   WScript.Quit(1);
}

word.visible = true

// Open the base document
baseDoc = word.Documents.Open(sTheirDoc);

// Merge into the "My" document
if (parseInt(word.Version) < vOffice2000)
{
        baseDoc.Compare(sMergedDoc);
}
else if (parseInt(word.Version) < vOffice2007)
{
        baseDoc.Compare(sMergedDoc, "Comparison", wdCompareTargetNew, true, true);
} else {
    baseDoc.Merge(sMergedDoc);
}

// Show the merge result
if (parseInt(word.Version) < 12)
{
    word.ActiveDocument.Windows(1).Visible = 1;
}

// Close the first document
if (parseInt(word.Version) >= 10)
{
   baseDoc.Close();
}

// Show usage hint message
WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
if(WSHShell.Popup("You have to accept or reject the changes before\nsaving the document to prevent future problems.\n\nWould you like to see a help page on how to do this?", 0, "TSVN Word Merge", 4 + 64) == 6)
{
    WSHShell.Run("http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/assistance/HP030823691033.aspx");
}
```

Comment: that code is just using the interop.word class compare and merge methods which don't merge(append) two completely different documents, it just merges for track changes